# Option for the GOOGLETRANSLATE function that translates differently from the official Google Translate website

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

Using the `GOOGLETRANSLATE` formula:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1,"en","pt-BR")
```

When trying to translate the text:

```
From a $ 180m ‘goal machine’ to Spurs star: Man City’s best options for Aguero successor
```

The very poorly produced result is:

```
A partir de US $ 180 milhões ‘máquina objetivo’ para Spurs estrelas: melhores opções do homem da cidade para Aguero sucessor
```

The translation of the spreadsheet does not change the words of the place to fit the translation perfectly and for example:

Man City which is the name of a football team or another example Jonas Rice, on the website he analyzes it as personal names and does not translate, already in the spreadsheet he translates as if they were the words Man that comes from man and woman and Rice as the food called rice.

```
Man City ≠ Homem Cidade
Man City = Man City

Jonas Rice ≠ Jonas Arroz
Jonas Rice = Jonas Rice
```

The result when translating through the website (https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=pt&op=translate) is:

```
De uma ‘máquina de golos’ de $ 180 milhões a estrela do Spurs: as melhores opções do Man City para o sucessor de Aguero
```

I tried to use IMPORTXML to directly use the google website:

```
=IMPORTXML(
https://translate.google.com.br/?sl=en&tl=pt&text=From%20a%20%24180m%20%E2%80%98goal%20machine%E2%80%99%20to%20Spurs%20star%3A%20Man%20City%E2%80%99s%20best%20options%20for%20Aguero%20successor&op=translate,
"//span")
```

But in the result the translation is not included, it only comes with the original text.

What could I do to get a better quality translation? Is there any script or `IMPORTXML` option for this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `What could I do to get a better quality translation?`, as a direction, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to translate the following situation.

  - From

    ```
      From a $ 180m ‘goal machine’ to Spurs star: Man City’s best options for Aguero successor
    ```
  - To

    ```
      De uma ‘máquina de golos’ de $ 180 milhões a estrela do Spurs: as melhores opções do Man City para o sucessor de Aguero
    ```

In this case, how about using the custom function created by Google Apps Script? When Google Apps Script is used, Language Service can be used. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and please put the custom function of `=SAMPLE("text")` to a cell.

```
const SAMPLE = text => LanguageApp.translate(text, "en", "pt-BR");
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Class LanguageApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app)